# Align one div to the bottom of another

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several layers of `div`'s with the initial one's setting up the background image (including setting the `div` size to screen size) etc and final one being some text.  I want the text to then line up at the bottom of the `div` containing the background image.  I'm using javascript to change the background image and the text every few seconds, so this is my HTML.

```
<section class="documentary" id='documentary'>
    <div class="documentary-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-7">
                    <div class='film-title' id="film1">
                       <h1>Flim 1 Title</h1>
                       <p>Text about film 1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='film-title' id="film2">
                      <h1>Film 2 Title</h1>
                      <p>Text about film 2.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class='film-title' id="film3">
                       <h1>Film 3 Title</h1>
                       <p>Text about film 3.</p>
                       <a class="butt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="modal-button">View Trailer</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And here is the CSS for the relevant divs.

```
.documentary {
    background: url(../img/film1.jpg) no-repeat top center rgb(255,255,255);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0%;
    background-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}

.documentary-bg {
    padding: 0 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Standard*/
    min-height:100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    display:table-cell;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.film-title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

In short I want to align `.film-title` to the bottom of `.documentary-bg`.

Everything I've read says to use `{display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; }` on the `div` where you want things to align at the bottom but that is justing causing the min-height to be overruled and causing a right mess.

Comment: Give us a fiddle to play with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you googled for is for elements one next to other. In your case you have two solutions:

1. To set the row as `position: relative;`, than place your text with `position: absolute; bottom: 0; right; 0;`, or
2. To make the text same height as background image container and use `display: table-cell`, as you can see on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7mptnma2/1/), or in the snippet below.

```css
.documentary {
    background: url(../img/film1.jpg) no-repeat top center rgb(255,255,255);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0%;
    background-size: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -moz-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    -o-transition-property: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
    transition: background-image 300ms ease-in 200ms;
}

.documentary-bg {
    padding: 0 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(191, 191, 191), rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.7)); /*Standard*/
    min-height:100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    position:relative;
}
.documentary-bg div {
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.documentary-bg div.film-title {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="documentary" id='documentary'>
    <div class="documentary-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-7">
                    <div class='film-title' id="film1">
                       <h1>Flim 1 Title</h1>
                       <p>Text about film 1</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having your other css and your images to play with it's going to be hard to determine where you're at, so I broke it down into simpler terms. In the example below you have one wrapper item that contains three relatively positioned divs.  The key here is that they are position:relative.  Items nested in a relatively positioned element can be positioned absolutely in relation to the parent element, so the paragraph tags inside the divs, can be positioned to the bottom accomplishing what you need. You should be able to apply that logic to your setup.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
div.item {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
div.item p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Item 1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Item 2
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <p>
      Item 3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get the logic and I can see it working through in your example but when I've applied it, it moves the text from the` <p>` level `div` to the bottom of the first screen whereas the `div` it is associated with is further down.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle of your code as you see it? You have some bootstrap classes on those items that also may have styles that are effecting your result.